# Evaluating Statistical Likelihoods of Multiple Outcomes

Tags: statistics

So, I'm working on a statistical problem and need some help. Statistics are not my forte, so general and specific help would both be appreciated. Here's the problem, essentially: How do you find the likelihood that any one of multiple statistical outcomes is going to occur?

A basic example would be a coin flipping either heads OR tails, which is 100%.

My specific problem is a bit more challenging. There are 8 or so possible outcomes, and 1 has a 2% chance, another has a 4.5% chance, etc... How would I determine the probability that any one of them would occur?

Further, the chances increase as time goes on. Any idea on where I would find out more on evaluating statistical likelihoods that increase over time and the associated equations?

Thanks,
 - Cuindless

Comment: This is a pretty broad question that will probably need some more info from you to get a good answer. I will note though, that "likelihood" and "probability" have different distinct meanings in statistics. You can google that to see what they mean. Cheers.

Comment: How would I determine the probability that any one of them would occur? Use complementary event: $P(\texttt{"Any one of them would occur"})=1-P(\texttt{"None of them occurs"})$

Comment: Yeah, I realize I was being imprecise in my wording. Likelihoods refer to past events with known outcomes, while probabilities refer to future events. A good example would be my dice rolling metaphor below. I don't want to get too specific because this is for some proprietary work, but a multinomial distribution should work for my purposes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you have a multinomial distribution which has multiple categories. Something important though which you seem to have off in your question is that the sum of the probability of all possible outcomes must equal 1. So for the probability of Category A to increase, the probability of Category B, C, and/or D occurring must decrease. As for dealing with time, you can actually put that into the model itself as a variable.

Comment: Yes, a multinomial distribution is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! As for the probability of all outcomes summing to 1, the remainder would be "none of the other outcomes occur." For example, say I was rolling 6 dice. What is the probability that at least one die would roll a six? What is the probability that more than one die rolls a six? If we include "none of the dice rolls to six" than all the probable outcomes sum to one, but I'm only looking to solve for the probability that at least one die rolls a six. Does that make sense?